# Cannot save output to Excel Workbook when Python fills the data

Tags: python, excel

When I run the following code everything works find:

```
wb7 = load_workbook('define2.xlsx')
ws = wb7.worksheets[0]
ws.cell(row=3,column=2).value = "hey"
wb7.save('define2.xlsx')
```

But when I put the final line of code at the end of a different code I get an error message.  And the error is generated right as I step over the line:

```
wb7.save('define2.xlsx')
```

The error message I'm getting is

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not tuple
```

I find that strange because I see no reason why wb7 has to be a number.  All I'm trying to do is output some data to Excel then save the Excel workbook.  I've done this many times without any problems.  It must be the case that somehow the wb7 variable is getting changed but it is clearly not being changed.  In the debugger there is no evidence of wb7 being changed after running the code.  I also get the following in my console:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/worksheet.py:322: UserWarning: Unknown extension is not supported and will be removed
  warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2357, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)

  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1777, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script

  File "/Users/kylefoley/PycharmProjects/untitled3/temp5.py", line 1682, in <module>
    wb7.save('define2.xlsx')

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py", line 263, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 239, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename, as_template=as_template)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 222, in save
    self.write_data(archive, as_template=as_template)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 80, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets(archive)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 163, in _write_worksheets
    xml = sheet._write(self.workbook.shared_strings)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 778, in _write
    return write_worksheet(self, shared_strings)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/worksheet.py", line 198, in write_worksheet
    dim = Element('dimension', {'ref': '%s' % worksheet.calculate_dimension()})

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 420, in calculate_dimension
    get_column_letter(max_col), max_row
```

Here is the complete code:

```
wb7 = load_workbook('define2.xlsx')
ws = wb7.worksheets[0]
temp_list = []
category = ['r','s','t']
relat = []
srelat = []
trelat = []
word_type = []
atomic_relations = []
list1 = []
list4 = []
det = []
adj = []
adv = []
noun = []
cor = []
lcon = []
subo = []
synon = []
redundant = []
aux = []
atomic_relata = []
negg = []
dnoun = []
det_pairs = []
definitions = []
syn_pairs = []
relations = []
relations2 = []
ind_words = []
ind_num = []
particles = []
osent = []
sn = 1

i = 0
for row in ws.rows:
    i += 1
    if i == 430:
        pp = 5
    str1 = row[0].value
    str5 = copy.copy(str1)
    str2 = row[1].value
    if str1 != None and str2 != None:

        str3 = row[2].value
        defin = row[3].value
        if str2 != None:
            str2 = str2.strip()
        if str3 != None:
            str3 = str3.strip()
        atom = copy.copy(str1)
        str5 = str1[0:1]
        atom = atom[1:2]
        str8 = copy.copy(str1)
        str8 = str1[3:]
        if str5 in category:
            word_type.append([str3,str5])
        elif str5 != 'z':
            word_type.append([str2, str5])

        if str5 in category:
            if str5 == 'r':
                relat.append(str3)
            elif str5 == 's':
                srelat.append(str3)
            elif str5 == 't':
                trelat.append(str3)
            if atom == 'a':
                atomic_relations.append(str3)
                atom = 'b'
            list2a = [str2,str3]
            relations.append(list2a)
            relations2.append(str2)
        elif str5 == 'a':
            adj.append(str2)
        elif str5 == 'b':
            aux.append(str2)
        elif str5 == 'c':
            cor.append(str2)
        elif str5 == 'd':
            det.append(str2)
        elif str5 == 'e':
            adv.append(str2)
        elif str5 == 'l':
            lcon.append(str2)
        elif str5 == 'm':
            negg.append(str3)
        elif str5 == 'n':
            noun.append(str2)
        elif str5 == 'u':
            subo.append(str2)
        if atom == 'n':
            dnoun.append(str2)
        elif atom == 'a':
            atomic_relata.append(str2)
        elif atom == 'q':
            particles.append(str2)
        elif atom == 'r':
            redundant.append(str2)
        if atom == 'p' or atom == 'd':
            if atom == 'p':
                atom = 7
            elif atom == 'd':
                atom = 5
            list1a = [str2, atom]
            ind_words.append(str2)
            ind_num.append(list1a)
        elif atom == 's':
            str6 = defin[defin.find("=")+1:-1]
            str6 = str6.strip()
            str7 = defin[1:defin.find("=")]
            str7 = str7.strip()
            list3a = [str7, str6, defin]
            syn_pairs.append(list3a)
            synon.append(str7)
        elif atom == 'n':
            str6 = defin[defin.find(".")+1:]
            str7 = defin[:defin.find(".")]
            det_pairs.append([str7, str6, str2])
        if atom != 'a':
            if str5 in category:
                definitions.append([str3, defin])
            else:
                definitions.append([str2, defin])

words = [adj, cor, det, adv, lcon, noun, relat, srelat, trelat, subo, aux, negg, dnoun]
word_type.sort()
syn_pairs.sort()

del word_type[0]
test_sent = []

j = 0
for i in ws.rows:
    j += 1
    if j > 263:
        break
    if j == 169:
        pp = 7
    str1 = i[0].value
    str2 = i[1].value
    if str1 != None:
        str2 = str2.strip()
        if str1[1:2] == 's' and j>139:
            str3 = findinlist(str2,syn_pairs,0,1)
            if str3 == None:
                pp = 7
            str4 = findinlist(str3, word_type,0,1)
            if str4 == None:
                pp = 7
            ws.cell(row=i,column=1).value = str4 + 'sx'


wb7.save('define2.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: instead of

```
ws.cell(row=i,column=1).value = str4 + 'sx'
```

I should write:

```
ws.cell(row=j,column=1).value = str4 + 'sx'
```

The value to the right of the = sign has to be a number whereas the i is a row not a number.

Comment: Maybe the lesson here is to use meaningful names. ;-)